# Print message of exception inside a ParseException

Tags: java, android

I've got a simple log in/signup form for an app I'm developing as part of a course.
I'm using ParseUser to sign up users and log them in.

When the user enters a username that already exists, a Toast is shown...

```
    ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(password);

    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign up successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                Log.i("Sign up", "failed. Reason - " + e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign up failed. " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
```

...with the error message from `e.getMessage()`, e.g., "Sign up failed. Account already exists for this username."

However, if the user does not enter anything, i.e., leaves either the pw or username field blank, [I get this in the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvSbs.png)

and the following in the logs: `I/Sign up: failed. Reason - com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Username cannot be missing or blank`

What I want to see is only the error message `Username cannot be missing or blank`, which is the ".getMessage()" of the second exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

How would I go about doing that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main options I see here:

1. Get the cause using `getCause()`, and call `getMessage()` on the cause, rather than from the top level exception itself.
2. Manually format the string by getting the last instance of the "Exception" substring and discarding everything before (and including) it; this should probably be used as a last-resort option since it increases complexity and decreases readability.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. :)

When would one use the second option?

Comment: When the first option doesn't work for your situation or causes more problems than it solves. :P

Comment: Oh, okay then. Thanks again, Austin!